# make an NA prior a none NA value (1) a 0 using R

Tags: r, date, na

I've got the following data frame df

```
time <- c("01/01/1951", "02/01/1951", "03/01/1951", "04/01/1951", "05/01/1951", "06/01/1951", "07/01/1951", "08/01/1951", "09/01/1951", "10/01/1951", "11/01/1951", "12/01/1951", "13/01/1951", "14/01/1951", "15/01/1951", "16/01/1951", "17/01/1951", "18/01/1951", "19/01/1951", "20/01/1951", "21/01/1951", "22/01/1951", "23/01/1951")
member <- c(1,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(time, member) 
df$time = as.Date(df$time,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I like the day with an NA value for "member" before a day where member is 1 to become a 0, UNLESS there is a 1 on the day before a 1 (two consecutive ones), I wouldnt want the 1 to become a 0, just the NA values before a 1.

the desired data frame would be:

```
df
         time member
1  01/01/1951      1
2  02/01/1951     NA
3  03/01/1951     NA
4  04/01/1951      3
5  05/01/1951     NA
6  06/01/1951     NA
7  07/01/1951     NA
8  08/01/1951     NA
9  09/01/1951      0
10 10/01/1951      1
11 11/01/1951      1
12 12/01/1951     NA
13 13/01/1951      2
14 14/01/1951     NA
15 15/01/1951     NA
16 16/01/1951     NA
17 17/01/1951     NA
18 18/01/1951      0
19 19/01/1951      1
20 20/01/1951     NA
21 21/01/1951     NA
22 22/01/1951     NA
23 23/01/1951     NA
```

ideas?

Comment: I don't understand. Rows 10 and 11 are two consecutive 1s, so why is Row 9 changed to `0` in the result? Doesn't your "UNLESS" mean that row 9 should still be `NA`?

Comment: I meant that I dont want the 1 before a 1 to turn into a 0.

Comment: Right, you only want `NA` values changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we need to check if `df$member` is `NA` and the next value is 1. When both of those are true, we set `df$member` equal to 0:

```
df$member[is.na(df$member) & c(df$member[-1] == 1, FALSE)] = 0
df
#          time member
# 1  1951-01-01      1
# 2  1951-01-02     NA
# 3  1951-01-03     NA
# 4  1951-01-04      3
# 5  1951-01-05     NA
# 6  1951-01-06     NA
# 7  1951-01-07     NA
# 8  1951-01-08     NA
# 9  1951-01-09      0
# 10 1951-01-10      1
# 11 1951-01-11      1
# 12 1951-01-12     NA
# 13 1951-01-13      2
# 14 1951-01-14     NA
# 15 1951-01-15     NA
# 16 1951-01-16     NA
# 17 1951-01-17     NA
# 18 1951-01-18      0
# 19 1951-01-19      1
# 20 1951-01-20     NA
# 21 1951-01-21     NA
# 22 1951-01-22     NA
# 23 1951-01-23     NA
```

Comment: that works, thank you. what if I also wanted to make the NA two rows before a 3 a 0 as well? df$member[is.na(df$member) & c(df$member[-2] == 3, FALSE)] = 0 would it be like this?

Comment: You'd need to shift 2 rows, so `c(df$member[-(1:2)] == 3, FALSE, FALSE)`. You're removing the first two rows (because they don't count if you are looking two rows before) and then sticking two FALSE values on the end so the total length stays the same.